# JQuery - addClass when the class is bound to an id

Tags: jquery, css

I have this CSS rule:

```
#panelSeparator .active {
    background: #fff url(../img/vgrabber.gif) no-repeat center;
    opacity: 0.7;  
}
```

I would like to do something like this in JS:

```
$('#panelSeparator').addClass('active');
```

How should I change the parameter of addClass in order to make that work?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I don't see the problem here. That code should work just fine.

Comment: the jQuery will work fine only if the CSS selectors are chained, `#panelSeparator.active {}` means to select an element with **both** the ID and the class, which is what the jQuery is doing, adding the class to the same element - as per [Brian Fisher's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203218/jquery-addclass-when-the-class-is-bound-to-an-id/6203286#6203286)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try removing the space between #`panelSeparator .active` so it is `#panelSeparator.active`.

Comment: +1, to elaborate it's because `#panelSeparator .active` refers to an element with the class `active` that is after an element with an id of `panelSeparator` in the DOM tree. Removing the spaces makes it look for an element with the ID and Class.

Answer (score 0):

your css defines a class which is bound to all children of elements with the id 'panelSeperator'. You should use the jQuery.children() function (http://api.jquery.com/children/);

```
$('#panelSeparator').children().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same CSS, then you'll need to do something like `$('#panelSeparator div').addClass('active');` in Javascript. Basically, you'd have to select an element inside the #panelSeparator element.

Or you can keep the same Javascript and just change the CSS to `#panelSeparator.active`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try,

```
$('#panelSeparator').addClass('panelSeparator active');
```